# Trestle TinyMCE Gem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dom')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-6, trestle-admin

After clicking on the source-code button of the editor, the complete text vanishes.

Gem details:

```
gem 'trestle', '0.9.2'
gem 'trestle-auth', '0.3.0'
gem 'trestle-search', '0.4.1'
gem 'trestle-tinymce', '0.3.1'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '5.10.1'
```

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: @AndreaGiovacchini - NotYet, tried different ways but no success.

Comment: Ok, if I find a solution I'll tell you

Comment: If you put gem 'tinymce-rails', '4.9.11' in the Gemfile the problem disappears, maybe it is related to Tinymce 5